# C# MVC Razor view: what is wrong?

Tags: c#, razor

Hello i have a view like:

```
@{
    var isClient = true;
}


<script type="text/javascript">

@if (isClient)
{
    <text>

    function test() {
        var arr = ["'1'","'2'","'3'","'4'"];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            try {
                var rep = "\""; @* this line fails for razor. *@
                console.log(arr[i].replace(new RegExp("'", 'g'), rep));
            }
            catch (ex) {
                throw "Exception occured during iteration"
            }
        }
    }

    </text>
}
</script>
```

I can't make it work for Razor. I seems, that line marked with comment produces compilation error. Removing this line will clear compilation error.

The only workaround for this i found is to replace "\""; with "\@Html.Raw("\"")" but that is nasty!

var rep = "\@Html.Raw("\"")";

Any ideas?

Edit:
I expect output html to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function test() {
        var arr = ["'1'","'2'","'3'","'4'"];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            try {
                var rep = "\"";
                console.log(arr[i].replace(new RegExp("'", 'g'), rep));
            }
            catch (ex) {
                throw "Exception occured during iteration"
            }
        }
    }    
</script>
```

IT Man

Comment: Comments in Razor views are entered with `@*comment*@`.

Comment: Please update your question with the expected HTML you are expecting to generate from this code (including the `<script>` and `</script`>).

Comment: -> @MichałTurczyn : changed to razor comment but i belive thats not the problem in this case.

Comment: Oh, it's in JS part... that is tricky. I would suggest separating JS to another files if possible (I am not that familiar with JS).

Comment: Why are you downvoting this question?

Comment: That js code that you have shown us could have been done in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will work for you.

```
@{
    var isClient = true;
}    

@if (isClient)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function test() {
            var arr = ["'1'", "'2'", "'3'", "'4'"];

            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                try {
                    var rep = "\""; @* this line fails for razor. *@
                    console.log(arr[i].replace(new RegExp("'", 'g'), rep));
                }
                catch (ex) {
                    throw "Exception occured during iteration"
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
} 

  else {
         <script>
              alert("else part")
         </script>
    }
```

Comment: Well thats only partial solution. I my case i need to conditinally generate parts javascript. So @if statement should be inside <script> tags.

Comment: @ITMan else part can also contain `<script>` tag. Please check else part in answer.

Comment: But i need to supply function definition conditionally inside single script tag. Case A: <script> function a(){} <script> Case <script> functiona(){} function b(){} </script>, code for function a() would be rendundant

Comment: No need to repeat `function a()` because it will be global across multiple `<script>` blocks

Comment: Well - not in my case i use this view to dynamically generate js library - as a seperate file (eg. mylib.js) , see: http://blog.pmunin.com/2013/04/dynamic-javascript-css-in-aspnet-mvc.html. In that case i use <script> tags only to wrap around javascript code - but finally <script> tags are removed as soon as rendered view returns to controller. Any way your solution is closest to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You write razor code inside script tag, it is the place for JavaScript code only

try this:

```
@{
   var isClient = true;
}


<script type="text/javascript">

if (@isClient)
{


   function test() {
       var arr = [1,2,3,4];

       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        try {
                var rep = "\"; 
                console.log(arr[i].replace(new RegExp("'", "g"), rep));
            }
            catch (ex) {
                throw "Exception occured during iteration"
            }
      }
   }

}
else {
     alert("else part")
}
</script>
```

Comment: if (isClient) is part of view logic - rendered on server side.

Comment: Well this example is trivial. In the real case else block would contain much more javscript code. I don't want to expose this code to client if server side conditions aren't met. In your answer it would be exposed because no matter what value @isClient would be else part will be always rendered iniside view.